# Pass form attributes to another php template in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, page-template, html

I know that this question gets asked a lot of times but I tried everything and still have problems figuring out why it's not working...

So I have a the following form (still not final):

```
<form id="doctor_search" >

    <h1>Doctor search</h1>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Fill at least 1 of the following fields</legend>
      <label for="name" name="fn">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="first_name">
      <label for="name">Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="last_name">

      <label>Gender:</label>
      <input type="radio" id="fem" value="fem" name="doc_gen"><label for="fem" class="light">Female</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="male" value="male" name="doc_gen"><label for="male" class="light">Male</label>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
    <label for="job">Specialization:</label>
    <select id="job" name="user_job">

        <option value="frontend_developer">Pediatry</option>
        <option value="php_developor">General medicine</option>
        <option value="python_developer">Cardiology</option>
        <option value="rails_developer"> Geniology</option>
        <option value="web_designer">Endocrinology</option>

    </select>

      <label>Interests:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="development" value="interest_development" name="user_interest"><label class="light" for="development">...</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="design" value="interest_design" name="user_interest"><label class="light" for="design">...</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_business" name="user_interest"><label class="light" for="business">...</label>

    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" id="search-submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
```

I am following the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7ID_L91lIk&t=245s  but it doesn't really work as intented.

I have the following button event listener:

```
userSubmitButton.addEventListener( 'click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var gen;
        if(document.getElementById('fem').checked) gen = true; 
        else if(document.getElementById('male').checked) gen = false;
        else gen = null;
        var formData = {
            'gender' : gen
        };
        adminAjaxRequest( formData, 'doctor_search_process' );
    } );
```

At the moment I only use one attribute, the gender. My ajax request is the following:

```
var adminAjaxRequest = function( formData, action ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: SliderData.adminAjax,
            data: {
                action: action,
                data: formData
                //submission: document.getElementById( 'xyq').value,
                //security: screenReaderText.security
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if ( true === response.success ) {
                    alert( 'this was a success' );
                } else {
                    alert( 'You Suck' );
                }
            }

        });
    };
```

sliderData.adminAjax is basically url to admin-ajax.php. From here I add the action in functions.php

```
function doctor_search_process() {
$g = $_POST[ 'data' ][ 'gender' ];
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_doctor_search_process', 'doctor_search_process' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_doctor_search_process', 'doctor_search_process');
```

The problem is that the ajax process always fails... And, on top of that, I need to list posts with tags that have female or male. As I understand, it can be done only in page/template php file. Even if it worked, I don't know how to pass it to a page php...
Can someone help me? Why does my ajax always fails? My webpage is http://medclinic.x10host.com/sample-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have read thru the WP Codex, so you have basically set things up right. A couple little things I would suggest:

**Make sure the URL var is correct**

You are using `sliderData.adminAjax` to point to the AJAX URL. I have always been able to simply use `ajaxurl` because WP defines it for me. I would make the switch to make sure you are hitting the right target. (It's always possible your `sliderData` object is not in scope, or the member variable didn't get set correctly.)

**Fix PHP file**

In the function `doctor_search_process()`, you try to access the POST variable as if it's a two-dimensional array. I've never seen an example that suggests this. It's always worked for me to access the POST var I want directly. I think you should try:

`$g = $_POST[ 'gender' ];`

But then you should echo it back.

```
function doctor_search_process() {
    $g = $_POST[ 'gender' ];
    echo $g;
    wp_die();
}
```

I have read on this forum that if the PHP file doesn't "die()" then AJAX will not the process has finished.

**Improve javascript**

I really like the way you pass the AJAX action into the javascript function that initiates the AJAX. However, you don't seem to be concluding the AJAX call correctly. In your `success` function, you are catching both success and failure. Generally, failure is caught by its own function. Also, the success function always comes first, so it doesn't have to be explicit. This is what works for me:

```
$.post(
  data: {
     action: action,
     data: formData
  },
  function( content ) {
     alert( content );
  } ).fail( function( ) {
    alert( "you suck" );
});
```

Comment: Hello.I made the changes you suggested (except the improve javascript, do I have to copy the code above instead of my "sucess: " part?) but it is still not working. It's as if it doesn't access the functions.php file. It doesn't echo the variable $g. The response is always 0.

Comment: I looked at your web page. Do you know the Chrome Dev Tools console shows missing .css files? Makes me wonder if your functions.php is in the wrong place. However, the result I got from the AJAX call was 'null gender' which came from line 102 (in the success function). I would guess this means your AJAX handler is being called but the data isn't arriving correctly.

Comment: Exactly. I have run the   isset($_POST[ 'gender' ])  function in php and it always says that gender is not set. i tried echoing json_encode with the same result. I do receive correctly the gender attribute in javascript, I do connect with the function in function.php but I don't receive the value itself... Very strange

Comment: Try setting `gender` explicitly and passing that. The code does set it to null in some cases. Maybe try `else gen = "no gender";` Also, wouldn't it be easier to use jQuery to get the value of the radio buttons?

Comment: well, i need to pass it to another page php file and be redirected to it. I can't find a way to pass it to another page using jquery...

Comment: I don't understand. I just thought you could do this: 
`if($('#fem').checked) gen = true;`

It seems the best way to pass a value to another php file would be to call a function and pass the parameter in the function arguments.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do it with just Javascript but I need to pass them to php of the page because I'll need to use some functions to query a database and show the posts with tag female. If I just pass it with Javascript it  is not possible, right? This is why everyone tell me to use Ajax and I'm quite new to it

Comment: Let's not put the cart before the horse. Try passing a test value via AJAX and returning it to make sure it is working for you. When it is, mark this question as answered and ask a different question on this forum.

Comment: When you post that other question, post a link to it in a comment so I can find it and try to help.